# Javascript: Save variable field names

Tags: javascript, string

I have 2 strings. One represents the variable name and the other the value.
This might explains it better:

```
var data = ['varName', 'content'];
var obj = { data[1]: data[2] }
```

The other post I've found yet only refer to an objects name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set it like this:

```
var data = ['varName', 'content'];
var obj = {};
obj[data[0]] = data[1];
```